# How to get multiple values from a Array by indexes in Ruby

Tags: ruby, arrays

There is a Array `a = %w(a b c d e)`, and want to get second and last values by indexes.

I can get values by `a[1], a[-1]`, but I need write `a` twice.
Is there a way to get a Array by like `a.at(1, -1)`?

Comment: Did you look at the documentation for Array? Your answer is there.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Yes possible. Use [Array#values_at](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/Array.html#method-i-values_at) method.

> Returns an array containing the elements in self corresponding to the given selector(s).The selectors may be either integer indices or ranges.

```
a = %w{ a b c d e f }
a.values_at(1, 3, 5)          # => ["b", "d", "f"]
a.values_at(1, 3, 5, 7)       # => ["b", "d", "f", nil]
```

Here is from your example :-

```
2.1.0 :001 > a = %w(a b c d e)
 => ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e"] 
2.1.0 :002 > a.values_at(1,-1)
 => ["b", "e"] 
2.1.0 :003 >
```